# Packaging JRuby binaries into executable jar

Tags: jruby

Have downloaded the Jruby binaries on windows, installed the necessary gems i needed. How then do I re-package the whole Jruby binaries into an executable jar ?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a JRuby project, simply run

```
rake jar
```

to see all available tasks:

```
rake -T
```